# Access MS SQL Server from a web application present in linux machine?

Tags: linux, sql-server-2005, tomcat6

I can access MS Sql from a web application resides in Windows. But it is not possible with a web application reside in Linux. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver is used in this application. 
Following are the configurations.

Tomcat 6
MS SQL 2005
jdk6
Driver :com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't problems. Just make sure that the server in which resides the web app have network visibility on the server where reside MS SQL 2005. 
Make sure also that MS SQL 2005 have network connection enabled. To do that look at those lines from microsoft documentation:

---

"You must enable remote connections for each instance of SQL Server 2005 that you want to connect to from a remote computer. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server 2005, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Surface Area Configuration.
2. On the SQL Server 2005 Surface Area Configuration page, click Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections.
3. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Remote Connections, click Local and remote connections, click the appropriate protocol to enable for your environment, and then click Apply.

   Note Click OK when you receive the following message:
     Changes to Connection Settings will not take effect until you restart the Database Engine service.
4. On the Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections page, expand Database Engine, click Service, click Stop, wait until the MSSQLSERVER service stops, and then click Start to restart the MSSQLSERVER service."

---